# How to append randomized float values into array within loop

Tags: python, arrays

I have a set of randomized float values that are to be arranged into an array at the end of each loop that produces 67 of them, however, there are 64 total loops.
As an example, if I had 4 values per loop and 3 total loops of integers, I would like it to be like this:
values = [[0, 4, 5, 1],[6, 6, 5, 3],[0,0,0,7]]
such that I could identify them as separate arrays, however, I am unsure of the best way to append the values after they are created, but am aware of how to return them. Forgive me as I am unskilled with the logic.

```
import math
import random

funcs = []
coord = []

pi = math.pi

funcAmt = 0
coordAmt = 0
repeatAmt = 0
coordPass = 0

while funcAmt < 64:
    while coordAmt < 67:
        coordAmt += 1
        uniform = round(random.uniform(-pi, pi), 2)
        print("Coord [",coordAmt,"] {",uniform,"} Func:", funcAmt + 1)
        if uniform in coord:
            repeatAmt += 1
            print("Repeat Found!")
            coordAmt -= 1
            print("Repeat [",repeatAmt,"] Resolved")
            pass
        else:
            coordPass += 1
            coord.append(uniform)
    #<<<Append Here>>>
    funcAmt += 1
    coord.clear()
    coordAmt = 0
```

In my given code above, it would be similar to:
func = [
[<67 items>],
...63 more times
]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "append here" logic should append the coordinate list and then clear that list for the next iteration of the outer loop:

```
funcs.append(coord[:])    # The slice notation makes a copy of the list
coord.clear()             # or simply coord = []
```

You should learn to use a `for` loop.  This will simplify your looping: you don't have to maintain the counts yourself.  For instance:

```
for funcAmt in range(64):
    for coordAmt in range(67):
        ...
```

You might also look up how to make a "list comprehension", which can reduce your process to a single line of code -- a long, involved line, but readable with proper white space.

Does that get you moving?

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways around this.  Instead of using `while` lists and counters, you could just use `for` loops.  Or at least do that for the outer loop, since it looks like you still want to check for repeats.  Here's an example using your original dimensions of 3 and 4:

```
from math import pi
import random

coord_sets = 3
coords = 4

biglist = []
for i in range(coord_sets):

    coords_set = []
    non_repeating_coords = 0
    while non_repeating_coords < coords:
        new_coord = round(random.uniform(-1.0*pi, pi), 2)
        if new_coord not in coords_set:
            coords_set.append(new_coord)
            non_repeating_coords += 1

    biglist.append(coords_set)

print(biglist)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets because they don't allow duplicate values:

```
from math import pi
import random

funcs = []
funcAmt = 0

while funcAmt < 64:  # This is the number of loops
    myset = set()
    while len(myset) < 67:  # This is the length of each set
        uniform = round(random.uniform(-pi, pi), 2)
        myset.add(uniform)
    funcs.append(list(myset))  # Append randomly generated set as a list
    funcAmt += 1

print(funcs)
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can benefit from arrays in `numpy`:

```
import numpy as np

funcs = np.random.uniform(-np.pi, np.pi, [63, 67])
```

This creates an array of shape (63, 67) from uniform random between -pi to pi.